# Finding the critical points of the damped oscillation equation $f(x) = e^{-x} \sin 2 x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have the following function:

$$ f(x) = e^{-x} \sin(2x) $$

I have found the derivative of the function to be

$$ f'(x) = e^{-x} (2\cos(2x)-\sin(2x)) .$$

How would one go about solving $ f'(x) = 0 $?

I have tried multiple ways of going about it, but I don't seem to get it quite right.

Range: $ x\in [0, 2\pi] $

Comment: Check your derivative!

Comment: Corrected it just now @SimonS

Comment: Try to convert $2 \cos(2x)-\sin(2x)$ into amplitude-frequency-phase form, i.e. $A \cos(2(x-\phi))$. This is not extremely difficult though it is somewhat tedious. Once you have done that, $x=\frac{\cos^{-1}(0)}{2} + \phi$ (which of course is not a single number, but infinitely many).

Comment: Working on it. I've forgotten to include the range in which to find the values. I've updated it now @Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Since $e^{-x}$ is never zero, $f'(x) = 0$ iff $$2 \cos 2x - \sin 2x = 0 .$$
Can we rearrange this equation to write it in terms of a single trigonometric function?

Comment: Ive found the following:

$$ \sqrt(5) \cdot sin(1.107 - 2x ) $$

@Travis

Comment: How did you get $1.107$? Alternatively, what happens if you divide both sides of the above equation by $\cos 2x$?

Comment: Ah, I found the exact same value by doing the following

$ 2cos(2x) - sin(2x) = 0 $
$ 2 - tan(2x) = 0 $
$ -tan(2x) = -2 $
$ tan(2x) = 2 $
$ 2x = tan^{-1}(2) $
$ 2x = 1.107 + k \cdot \pi $

$ x = 0.5535 + k \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} $

@Travis how is that?

Comment: Seems like I've found the answer by doing both methods. Thank you for your help

Comment: @TorAndreHaugdahl Yes, that's the idea!

Answer (score 0):

The exponential is never $0$, so you want $2 \cos(2x) - \sin(2x) = 0$.
Note that if $\alpha = \arctan(1/2)$, $\sin(2x-\alpha)$ is a multiple of $ 2 \cos(2x) - \sin(2x)$